# Check mysqli result if row already exists

Tags: php, duplicates

I'm trying to check if a row exist in my db like this:

```
 $uid = $_GET['queryString'];

    if(isset($_GET['queryString'])) {

    echo "New: ".$uid."<BR>";

    $query = "SELECT * FROM stuff WHERE $uid";

    // Escape Query
    $queryE = $db->real_escape_string($query);

        $results = $db->query($queryE);

        if(($results->num_rows) > 0) {
             echo "NO!";
        }
        else
        {
             echo "Make new row";

         }

    }
    else
    {
    echo 'Error!';
    }
```

But I keep getting the error: `Trying to get property of non-object in ....`

So if it exist I do one thing, if it doesn't I do the other, i've been searching for about an hour to find the cause, maybe I'm mixing up old PHP4 with my PHP5 stuff?

I've tried a lot, tried some examples but tend to get the error: `mysql_fetch_array() expects parameter 1 to be resource, string given`

Or should I check it in the query itself?

Comment: Do you know the story of [Bobby Tables](http://bobby-tables.com/)? What you're doing is a really really bad idea.

Comment: Your code looks problematic. The way it is written, I'd suggest you fix the many issues it has first before taking care of your concrete question. You probably have questions you want to ask first.

Comment: well, if you could point out the 'many issues' you think it has, besides the usual 'omg noob sql injection alert!'. And the fact I didn't include my $db definition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What line is the error on?!

If it is on the `real_escape_string` line, you haven't instantiated $db properly.

If it is on the `$results->num_rows` line, try changing

`$results = $db->query($queryE);` to:

```
if(!($results = $db->query($queryE))) {
    echo 'Make new row';
} else {
    // user likely exists, check $results
}
```

Also, you need to clean up the way you check the query string -- just process the query variable you want, rather than the whole string. Suggest also to use a different name for the query variable and the table column.